# Capturing Multiple Groups with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to formulate a regex in Java to capture multiple groups.  Here is the string (let's call is `output`) I am trying to capture from ...

```
ltm virtual MY_VM {
    rules {
        foo_bar
        baz
        qux-baz
    }
}
```

And I am trying to capture everything between the inner-most brackets, i.e. `foo_bar`, `baz`, and `qux-baz`.  So far I have ...

```
String regex = "ltm\\svirtual\\sMY_VM\\s\\{\\s*\\n\\s*rules\\s\\{\n\\s*([^\n]*)\\s*\\}\n\\s*\\}";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But this of course only matches if I only have one item in the list.  How can I modify my regex to match any number of capture groups in the inner-most brackets, assuming each group is separated by a newline character and any amount of whitespace as I have in my example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by @stribizhev at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069272/matching-on-substrings-in-delimited-list-using-regex) also works for this question:

```
String regex = "(?:\\brules\\s+\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s+([\\w-]+)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If pair checking is not required, this should work for you:

```
.*\{([^}]*)
```

in java it would be:

```
String regex = ".*\\{([^}]*)";
```

- **Note that you need the** `DOTALL` **flag**
- read the capture group `1`, all text within inner-most brackets will be there.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to include all the fluff before the capture groups in the regex?  ie the `ltm virtual MY_VM { rules {` and so on?

Comment: why do we need those? you just want the stuff with the "inner-most brackets", don't u? @user2150250 the `.*\{` has already matched `ltm virtual....{...{...{`

Comment: Inner-most brackets ideally including the text I specified.  It's not 100% necessary in my use case but I would really like to have it in there just in case.

Comment: so `ltm virtual MY_VM {` and `   rules {` are just fixed??

Comment: Yes they are.  Also, this seems to be matching everything in a single group, even including the `rules {` characters.  I want it to match `foo_bar`, `baz`, and `qux-baz` each in separate capture groups

Comment: @user2150250 there is `split()`, you could split and get each in array. Also if all things are fixed, you can just `replace()` those by empty, then split. If you love regex, just change my `.*\{` into `ltm.......{`

Comment: It's still matching everything in a single group instead of multiple groups.  I'd like to know how to accomplish it with regex ideally.

Comment: Yes, but is there still a relatively simple regex-based solution?

Answer (score -1):

I never used regExpr's in java uptill now, however if I do understand your problem correctly, the Kleene star operation will help you out.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star