# Matching on Substrings in Delimited List Using Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm attempting to formulate a regex in Java to capture multiple strings in a space-delimited list. Here is the string I am trying to capture from ...

```
String output = "regulations { qux def } standards none rules { abc-123 456-defghi wxyz_678  } security { enabled }";
```

And I want use a regex to match on each word in the space-delimited list between the brackets immediately following `rules`.  In other words, I would  like the regex to match on `abc-123`, `456-defghi`, and `wxyz_678`.  These substrings in this list can contain any characters except whitespace, and there can be any number of substrings in the list; I've just used the above 3 specifically to illustrate by example.  The following isn't working since I need to modify it to be able to match multiple times ...

```
String regex = "rules\\s\\{\\s([^\\s]*)\\s\\}";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

How could I modify the above regex to account for multiple possible matches and get the following output?

```
abc-123
456-defghi
wxyz_678
```

Comment: Do you need one regex approach? I think a 2-step approach will be more readable.

Comment: To be honest I'd really appreciate seeing both a single and double regex solution for my own learning's sake ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 1-step approach: use 1 regex to "match them all".

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wO9vK6/1):

```
(?:\brules\s+\{|(?!^)\G)\s+([\w-]+)
```

The regex is matching a whole word `rules` followed by 1 or more whitespace symbols and if it finds 1 or more whitespace followed by sequences of 1 or more alphanumeric symbols or hyphens, it also matches right after the last successful match. The word `rules` is a kind of a boundary for us here.

[Java code](https://ideone.com/brmgoa):

```
String output = "regulations { qux def } standards none rules { abc-123 456-defghi wxyz_678  } security { enabled }"; 
String regex = "(?:\\brules\\s+\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s+([\\w-]+)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(output);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Here is a 2-step approach: 1) get the substring between `rules {` and `}`, 2) split with whitespace.

```
String output = "regulations { qux def } standards none rules { abc-123 456-defghi wxyz_678  } security { enabled }"; 
String subst = output.replaceFirst("(?s)^.*\\brules\\s*[{]\\s*([^{}]+)[}].*$", "$1");
String[] res = subst.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/5ODJmQ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO9vK6/2).

The regex is much simpler, it just matches all up to and including `rules {`, then captures what is inside the `{...}`, and then matches `}` and the rest of string. With the backreference `$1` we restore this Group 1 value to `subst` variable. Then just split.

Comment: I will add more explanation for the first regex if you wish, I am a bit pressed for time right now. The main thing is that it matches and captures *subsequently* what you need with `([\w-]+)` after the `rules {`.

Comment: Hmm, the 1-step solution seems to be only capturing the first substring, `abc-123`. https://regex101.com/r/rH6dH3/1

Comment: You forget `g` modifier. In Java, `/g` is `while (m.find()) {...}`.